# Mysql concept of key for the same column with shared primary key

Tags: mysql, primary-key

As below code, I set chat_id and student_id as primary key so that the same chat will be added for another student_id. When it goes to production, the record will be a lot. Should I add one more index for student_id only so that the search will be faster for every user when they come back to the screen to see recently messages?

```
CREATE TABLE `tim_chat_recipients` (
`chat_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`student_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`message_status` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '1:New, 2:Read, 3:Deleted',
PRIMARY KEY (`chat_id`, `student_id`))COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci' ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: This is a 'compound primary key', *not* a 'shared primary key'. See the [information for a a 'shared primary key'](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/shared-primary-key/info) for details as to what the difference is.

Answer (score 0):

If the code is going to search for `student_id` *without* a `chat_id` then an index over *at least* `student_id` is *required* or **queries will result in non-scaling table/cluster scans**.. this is because the implicit cluster/index `(chat_id, student_id)` *can't* be used for index/reduction without a supplied chat_id.

This secondary index - `INDEX(student_id, [optionally other columns])` - *might* include other columns, either as part of the index or includes, although "appropriate selection" depends a good bit on the queries. In this case it may make sense to include the `message_status` column to be able to use "messages not seen" as a filter with minimal read-IO as it can avoid a probe back to the table/cluster. (Indices are about balancing maintenance/disk costs and benefits to queries.)

In short: for an index to be selected by the Query Planner in a [SARGABLE query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable), the *left parts* of the index must be known and mentioned in either the `WHERE` or, sometimes, the `JOIN .. ON` clauses.